# Can not get API from React hook (useEffect)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building e-commerce web site. I am having problem with getting product from API to show to user.

Here is my code:

```
import request from '../../utils/axiosInstances'

const [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState([])

//props.match.params.slug is title of product I want to take 
//in this line code I want to find product data get from API have props.match.params.slug        (title) I choose
const product = relatedProducts.find((e) => e.Slug === props.match.params.slug);


useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const {data} = await request.get('/product/getAll');
        
        setRelatedProducts(data);
    }
    fetchData();
},[]);
```

Using `useEffect`, I want to get product data from API, but `useEffect` is not running. What should I do?

Comment: Try this code: `const data = await fetch('/product/getAll');`

Comment: What is `request`? Give more information about that please? Is it an `axios` instance? Or something that is defined by yourself?

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot, @mahooresorkh it is an axios instance

Comment: The code seems ok! Did try to write a `console.log` in the `useEffect` callback body, to see if it is called or not?

Comment: Also in the network tab of the browser inspect window, to check if the Api gets called?

Comment: I tried but notthing return @mahooresorkh :((

Comment: tried which? `console.log` or network tab? 

Comment: both :((. because I use axios, network tab is nothing. I have already tried test API, it working ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250833/discussion-between-mahooresorkh-and-dop).